# Spread out Bootstrap images with captions within a column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a pricing comparison section of a Bootstrap 5 website, one column displays the images perfectly (without captions), however whenever I add a paragraph tag for the caption, the images stack on top of one another instead of staying inline in a row.

[image]

Here is the code for images without captions:

```
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="150">
        <div class="box">
          <h3>Basic</h3>
          <h4><sup>£</sup>4.50<span> / month</span></h4>
          <ul>
            <li><i class="bi bi-check-circle"></i>Web and mobile versions of Office apps only</li>
            <li><i class="bi bi-check-circle"></i>Chat, call, meet up to 300 attendees</li>
            <li><i class="bi bi-check-circle"></i>1 TB of cloud storage per user</li>
            <li><i class="bi bi-check-circle"></i>Business-class email</li>
            <li><i class="bi bi-check-circle"></i>Standard security</li>
            <li><i class="bi bi-check-circle"></i>Anytime phone and web support</li>
          </ul>

          <p>Web and mobile apps and services:</p>
        
          <img src="assets/img/Word_64x64.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
          <img src="assets/img/Excel_64x64.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
          <img src="assets/img/Outlook_64x64.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
          <img src="assets/img/PowerPoint_64x64.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
          <img src="assets/img/Microsoft_Teams_64x64.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
          <img src="assets/img/Outlook_64x64.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
          <img src="assets/img/Exchange_64x64.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
          <img src="assets/img/OneDrive_64x64.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
          <img src="assets/img/SharePoint_64x64.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
          
          <div class="btn-wrap">
            <a href="#" class="btn-buy">Buy Now</a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Here is the code for images with captions:

```
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-4 mt-lg-0" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="150">
        <div class="box featured">
          <h3>Premium</h3>
          <h4><sup>£</sup>16.60<span> / month</span></h4>
          <b><p>Everything in Business Standard, plus:</p></b>
          <ul>
            <li><i class="bi bi-check-circle white"></i>Advanced security
            <li><i class="bi bi-check-circle white"></i>Access and data control
            <li><i class="bi bi-check-circle white"></i>Cyberthreat protection</li>
            <li><i class="bi bi-check-circle white"></i>Mobile device management</li>
          </ul>

          <p>Desktop, web, and mobile apps and services:</p>

          <img src="assets/img/Excel_64x64.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"><p>Excel</p>
          <img src="assets/img/Outlook_64x64.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"><p>Outlook</p>
          <img src="assets/img/PowerPoint_64x64.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"><p>PowerPoint</p>
          <img src="assets/img/Microsoft_Teams_64x64.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"><p>Teams</p>
          <img src="assets/img/Outlook_64x64.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"><p>Outlook</p>
          <img src="assets/img/Exchange_64x64.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"><p>Exchange</p>
          <img src="assets/img/OneDrive_64x64.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"><p>OneDrive</p>
          <img src="assets/img/SharePoint_64x64.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"><p>SharePoint</p>
          <img src="assets/img/Access_64x64.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"><p>Access</p>
          <img src="assets/img/Publisher_64x64.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"><p>Publisher</p>

          <div class="btn-wrap">
            <a href="#" class="btn-buy">Buy Now</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

What do I need to change to keep the icons inline?

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: I would suggest that paragraph elements aren't really appropriate there anyway. Use actual figure caption elements or just spans with appropriate ARIA roles.

Comment: p is a block level element try to use span or give your  p display: inline;

Comment: Original question edited to show Bootstrap 5 version.

Figure / Caption elements is a much better way. However, the images are still stacked on top of one another rather than inline. I have wrapped all figure / figcaption elements into a div tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your `<img>` and the `<p>` inside a `<div>`. Since `<p>` is a block-level element, meaning that any element after `<p>` will automatically be added to a new line.
Here's my example

```
<div>
    <img/>
    <span>your text here</span>
</div>
```

Also note that I'm changing `<p>` with `<span>`

Comment: Thanks for your help. That seems to have aligned them better, but I still need the text to appear underneath eachimg, it's now appearing at the end of each img.

Comment: Okay so try to replace `<span>` back to `<p>`

Answer (score 1):

**Update code**

To centre all the content

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center">
  ...
</div>
```

Try to use the flex property of bootstrap

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <img/>
    <p>your text here</p>
</div>
```

for more details check out the bootstrap doc[https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/]

and You can wrap all the image div with flex-wrap

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: This is great and has now given me the desired layout I was looking for.

The only issue I have to solve now is there doesn't appear to be any spacing between the captions underneath the images, so some long product names like "SharePoint, OneDrive etc.) appear concatenated without any spacing.

Comment: Hey @CraigSmith check out this blog https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ you will get the better info about space and layout